# How do I only find newlines in a Regex?

Tags: regex, newline

I have a regex which finds newlines encoded in strings as `\n` (not the actual newline character), but it also finds encoded escaped newlines (`\\n`), like before the word "anything" in the string below.

```
var rg = '/(\\n)/g'
var str = 'so you can do pretty much \\nanything you want with it. \n\nAt runtime Carota has'
```

How can I find all of the newlines and none of the escaped newlines?

Here is a link with an example.  https://regexr.com/4fna7

Comment: try `/([\n])+?/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a **negative lookbehind**. This is used to look for characters behind text, but not include it in the capture.
Your rewritten regex would look like:
`(?<!\\)(\\n)`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to begin with a negated character class to ensure you do not pick up the double backslash:

```
var rg = '/[^\\](\\n)/g'
var str = 'so you can do pretty much \\nanything you want with it. \n\nAt runtime Carota has'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using JavaScript. In which case you can simply use the [Regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) like so:

```
/\n/
```

That would match all newline characters. If you can't use a Regex literal, JS also offers a constructor which takes a string

```
new RegExp('\\n')
```

In order to match the `\\n` you will need to escape the backslash:

```
/\\n|\n/
```

with constructor:

```
new RegExp('\\\\n|\\n')
```

Hope that helps.